# Is not liking the answer given for an existing question a reason enough to ask a duplicate/similar question?

Tags: discussion, questions, exact-duplicates

- [Past tense of RSVP](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33786/past-tense-of-rsvp)
- [Past participle of a verb created from an acronym](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1819/past-participle-of-a-verb-created-from-an-acronym)

The OP of the first question declares he asked a different question because he didn't like the accepted answer given in the other question. Is it a reason enough to create a similar/duplicate question?

Considering that the topic of second question is broader than the topic of the first one, and that the answers given for the second question covers two different acronyms used as verbs, isn't the first question a duplicate of the second one? Is there any reason to think that each acronym used as verb is a special (and independent) case?

Comment: As a special case, I wonder what would happen when the existing question has not been answered. Would other users ask the question again because they don't find the answer they are looking for?

Comment: that's what I assumed was what a user would do because of the post script after a question, as you brought up in your other question on Meta.

Comment: Also, I didn't know how to search for the "original" question. I searched for RSVP before asking and no one asked a question similar to mine, so I thought my question was unique.

Comment: Asking a question that is duplicate of another one is not a negative thing, nor is the fault of who asked the last question. There are questions that only users who frequented the site from the beginning know of; in this case, I asked the other question, and it was easy for me  to report the question was a duplicate. I want to be sure it's clear we don't put the blame on who asked a question that in some form was already asked. Duplicate questions are helpful, simply for the fact they give more visibility to the duplicated question, and allow more users to find it.

Comment: Yes, in theory, that would be nice, but it seems (especially on THIS stackexchange site) that its the worst faux pas imaginable and always ends with the questioner feeling stupid (ie I, for the most part, only get negative responses from people on this site). I don't know how to bring up the original question because of clarity without asking a new question. And when I ask a question in chat, it doesn't get answered... So I'm at a loss.

Comment: I have to say that my experience on SE sites have been worst in other sites than on EL&U, if we exclude a specific case of a particular user who kept to say my answers were duplicate of his answers, even if he was saying the opposite of what I was saying. In my experience, users on EL&U are nicer than in other SE sites; users ready to say "Did you google before to ask the question?" are present here as in any other SE site, though.

Comment: I guess its just my experience. I am apart of around 11 SE sites and the only site that I've ever recieved explicitly rude and pretentious behavior on a constant basis is this one. Even in Math where every answer is exact and absolute, the members are still willing to help users to the answers rather than just saying, "No, you're wrong" like I see countless times on this site.